# UIBarButtonItem Text does not show up on UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to place a toolbar one top of the UIDatepicker to make user close it after choosing the date. Unfortunately the button text is invisible (or somewhere behind but I could not get a meaningful result when using view hierarchy debugger). Although the button is clickable and works as intended. Only that, no one can predict there is a button. Code is below. Note that everything is created dynamically. By the way I am fairly new to ios programming.

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.date = Date()
datePicker.locale = .current
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.barStyle = .default
toolbar.isTranslucent = true
toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.blue
toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
toolbar.sizeToFit()
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dateDoneButtonClicked))
toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
answerField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar // answerField is a UITextField
answerField.inputView = datePicker
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
```

I have searched, and seen similar questions and there were some workarounds. I am going to show these workarounds as well, but still it does not explain why the code above does not work.

Adding image seems to work:

```
let donebuttonIcon = UIImage(named: "below-arrow")
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dateDoneButtonClicked))
doneButton.image = donebuttonIcon
doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
```

or adding a button myself:

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .system)
myButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
myButton.sizeToFit()
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateDoneButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)
toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
```

Images related to all these codes are below:

First code result:

[image: First Code Result]

Second code result:

[image: Second Code Result]

Third code result:

[image]

Comment: Your first code is perfectly works when I try . There may be a problem with the storyboard or if you have customized the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting:

```
let donebuttonIcon = UIImage(named: "below-arrow")
doneButton.image = donebuttonIcon
```

try this:

```
doneButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "below-arrow"), forState: .normal)
```

I am not sure though as I am also new to swift.

Comment: The solution with image works actually. But I want it to make it work by using swift's own done button initializer.

Comment: textFieldDOB.inputView = datePicker;

datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)